# Decomposing estimation error into bias and variance

Tags: probability, machine-learning

> Let $\Bbb X$ be an outcome space and let $\{P_{\theta} : \theta \in \Theta\}$ be a class of probability distributions on $\Bbb X$.  Let $X$ be an observed outcome generated by $P_{\theta}$ for some $\theta$ that is unknown to us.  We want to estimate $g(\theta)$ for a function $g$ on $\Theta$ using some decision rule $\delta$.  Show that for any decision rule $\delta$, the estimation error $\Bbb E_{\theta}[(g(\theta) - \delta(X))^2] = (\text{Bias}_{\theta}(\delta))^2 + \text{Var}_{\theta}(\delta)$ where $$\text{Bias}_{\theta}(\delta) \equiv g(\theta) - \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)] \text{ and }\text{Var}_{\theta}(\delta) \equiv \Bbb E_{\theta}[(\Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)] - \delta(X))^2]$$

I first set them equal and simplify to get:

$$\Bbb E_{\theta}[g(\theta)^2] - 2 \Bbb E_{\theta}[g(\theta)\delta(X)] + \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)^2] $$ $$=$$  $$g(\theta)^2 - 2g(\theta) \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)] + \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)]^2 + \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)]^2 - 2 \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)]^2 + \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)^2]$$

Then I reduce again to get:

$$\Bbb E_{\theta}[g(\theta)^2] - 2 \Bbb E_{\theta}[g(\theta)\delta(X)] = g(\theta)^2 - 2g(\theta) \Bbb E_{\theta}[\delta(X)]$$

But from here I can't see how to proceed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to show that last equation is true? If so, note that $g(\theta)$ is a constant.

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}_{\theta}}$Basically the way to show this result is to 1) note that $\E\left[(Y+Z)^2\right] = \E\left[Y^2\right] + \E\left[Z^2\right]$ if $\E[YZ] = 0$, and 2) use this result with $Y = g(\theta) - \E\left[\delta(X)\right]$ and $Z = \E[\delta(X)] - \delta(X)$, showing that indeed $\E[YZ] = 0$ here (*use that $Y$ is a constant here, so you have $\E[YZ] = Y\E[Z]$ and just have to show $\E[Z] = 0$*).

Comment: Why is $g(\theta)$ a constant?  It looks like it's a function of $\theta$ and I'm taking an expectation $g(\theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ so wouldn't that not be constant?

Comment: I think $\theta$ is an (unknown) constant and $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}$ means taking expectation with respect to $P_\theta$.

Comment: So if we assume $g(\theta)$ is constant, then is my way of proof correct or do I need to show the way you presented?